# WorksheetFunction.Average returns incorrect answer

Tags: excel, vba

Given the data in B2:D10 I wanted to find the average in each row use VBA array formula. Following a book example VBA Queue by Bill Jelen.

[image: Worksheet data]

```
Name    A   B   C   Answer  Manual Avg
A2      4   34  59  31.5    32.33333333
A3      45  83  74  59.5    67.33333333
A4      98  40  17  57.5    51.66666667
A5      95  8   83  89  62
A6      57  55  98  77.5    70
A7      14  21  17  15.5    17.33333333
A8      55  23  4   29.5    27.33333333
A9      80  15  77  78.5    57.33333333
A10     11  24  40  25.5    25
```

Answer in Column E is from this formula

```
Sub QuickFillAverage()
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myCount As Integer

myArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D10")

For myCount = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myCount + 1, 5).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Average(myArray(myCount, 1), myArray(myCount, 3))
Next myCount

End Sub
```

The answer in Column F is from

```
(B2+C2+D2) / 3
```

Done for each row to find the average. As you can see the answers are different. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the code is producing unexpected results is due to you only averaging two cells: `myArray(myCount, 1)` and `myArray(myCount, 3)`. You may be thinking of the `Range()` function that will return all cells between the two range values - but this isn't the case when you use an array.

You will need to include all three values in your average worksheet function:

```
WorksheetFunction.Average(myArray(myCount, 1), myArray(myCount, 2), myArray(myCount, 3))
```

Here is a function I created that will accept an array and average the array based on any row number provided (which will be your `myCount` number):

```
Function averageArrayRows(arr As Variant, ByVal myRow As Long) As Double

    Dim i As Long, mySum As Double

    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        mySum = mySum + arr(myRow, i)
    Next

    averageArrayRows = mySum / (UBound(arr, 2) - LBound(arr, 2) + 1)

End Function
```

Which you can use by:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myCount + 1, 5).Value = averageArrayRows(myArray, myCount)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I have encountered an error and I changed this part `myRow As Long` and used ByVal before this part to avoid the error. Also removed () after the variable arr in the first parameter

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I went ahead and updated for future readers who may have the same issue.

Comment: Note, the range passed directly to `WorksheetFunction.Average()` may contain empty or non-numeric cells, which are automatically excluded by the function from calculation. The behaviour of the above code is not the same when you pass an array returned by `Range.Value`.